# To check if a variable in Unix contains any of the string mentioned in a file bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a use case where a variable needs to be checked with multiple sub-strings in OR-condition and produce an output; as below:

```
if [ ! -z "$var" ]; then
   if [[ $var =~ .*Focus.* ]] || [[ $var =~ .*Wallet.* ]]; then
      ser=`echo $var|cut -d ' ' -f 2`
      echo " $ser is correct"
   else
      ser=`echo $var|cut -d ' ' -f 2`
      echo "!!!! $ser is incorrect !!!!"
    fi
fi
```

`var` contains pid and ServiceName. ServiceName is being checked if it contains any of the both substrings. It is running perfectly fine. But I want `var` to be checked in a list of substrings mentioned in a file instead, so that file can be modified later for more substrings.

Comment: *I want var to be checked in a list of substring mentioned in a file instead* -- Use awk or grep for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameter matching can use extended patterns:

```
#! /bin/bash

check=$(tr '\n' '|' < list_of_terms.txt)
check="@(${check%|})"

for service in Service1 GetFocus WalletLost ; do
    if [[ $service == *$check* ]] ; then
        echo $service matches
    fi
done
```

Comment: this would again leads to the same scenario when more substrings are required to check, have to edit the script.

Comment: @Anurodh: Check the update. You can populate $check from a file.

Comment: Many thanks, works as expected ! Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help you.

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/path/to/substring/file"
if [ ! -z "$var" ]; then
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
        if [[ $var == *"$line"* ]]; then
            echo "match: $line"
            break
        fi
    done <"$file"
fi
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome To Stack Overlow. Could you please add a bit more information why this answer would work and why you solved it this way?

Comment: Hi @menya, if I use this, my else block would print multiple times for the same $ser.